# How to loop through files (full path) in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

How do I do the equivalent in PowerShell? Note that I require the full path to each file.

```
# ksh
for f in $(find /app/foo -type f -name "*.txt" -mtime +7); do
   mv ${f} ${f}.old
done
```

I played around with Get-ChildItem for a bit and I am sure the answer is there someplace.

Comment: You should move your discoveries into answers so they can be upvoted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what mtime does here is the code to do everything else

```
gci -re -in *.txt "some\path\to\search" | 
  ?{ -not $_.PSIsContainer } |
  %{ mv $_.FullName "$($_.FullName).old" }
```

Comment: mtime  - File data was last modified n*24 hours ago.

Comment: `?{ $_.LastWriteTime -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-8) }`

Comment: No sure how to format a comment here so I can't paste the code and output. But I get the error "Move-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null." when I try the original answer. I am using PowerShell 1, perhaps that is an issue?

Comment: @Ethan, sorry I missed a pipeline operator when I formatted my code, please try again

Comment: You don't need to explicitly give `$_.FullName` as the first argument to `Move-Item`, though. It can figure it out from `$_` as well.

Comment: You can optimize this even further since Move-Item -destination parameter takes input by pipeline you can do this: ` ... | Move-Item -Dest {$_.FullName + '.old'}`.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to get me close to what I need. I was able to combine some of the information from Jared's answer with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523043/how-to-loop-through-files-and-rename-using-powershell) to figure it out.

```
foreach($f in $(gci -re -in hoot.txt "C:\temp")) {
   mv $f.FullName "$($f.FullName).old"
}
```

In the interest of sharing the wealth here is my function to simulate *nix find.

```
function unix-find (
   $path,
   $name="*.*",
   $mtime=0) 
   {
   gci -recurse -include "$name" "$path" | 
      where-object { -not $_.PSIsContainer -and ($_.LastWriteTime -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-$mtime)) } |
      foreach { $_.FullName }
   }
```