# Windows Powershell - Rename a list of files using a list from a text document

Tags: powershell, rename, batch-processing

I tried using the following code to rename a folder of files `"C:\www\folderx"` using a text list `"..\list.txt"`, but I can't figure out how to get the current file index:

```
Get-Childitem C:\www\folderx | % {
    $OldName = $_.name;
    $NewName = (GC ..\list.txt)[<CURRENT INDEX SHOULD GO HERE>];
    # Rename-Item -Newname $NewName;
    Write-Output $("Renamed {0} to {1}" -f $OldName,$NewName);
}
```

Comment: Never mind, I found a shorter solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1523078/1067499

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to loop through files and rename using PowerShell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523043/how-to-loop-through-files-and-rename-using-powershell)

Comment: For efficiency, don't put the `(GC ..\list.txt)` inside the foreach.  You're re-reading the contents of list.txt for every file passed down the pipeline.  You could put that in the begin block e.g. `... | Foreach -Begin {$i=0;$c = gc ..\list.txt} {$newname =  $c[$i++];...}`