# Rename wmv files from text file

Tags: powershell

I have folder which have 21 wmv files (01,02 ..21).i have text file which have titles for this wmv files. how do i call the text files and rename the wmv files using powershell. below is the code and there is second link for another powershell code which has similar request as mine but doesn't work for me. let me know if needed more clarity

```
get-childItem *.wmv | rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace '_',' ' 
-replace '\d{4}', '($0)' }
```

[Windows Powershell - Rename a list of files using a list from a text document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256501/windows-powershell-rename-a-list-of-files-using-a-list-from-a-text-document)

Comment: Show sample contents from the text file. Please use a spell checker, the question is hard to parse with all the typos.

Comment: Using punctuation in your question would help people actually understand your question as well.

Comment: the contents of text file are Getting Started with  Administration Fundamentals 
Different Types of cluster
hyper-v differnce     thanks for the help let me know if you need something

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below:

```
cd <your path>:\<wmv folder name>

ls *.wmv | Foreach -Begin {$i=1} `
   -Process {Rename-Item $_ -NewName ("new_name{0}.wmv" -f $i++) -whatif}
```

Comment: Do you mean `"new_name{0}.wmv"` ? `$i` is unused atm.

Comment: but how do i get the text file which has all subtitles ?

Comment: it doesn't work if i use something like this  
ls *.wmv | Foreach -Begin {$i=gc .\test.txt} `
   -Process {Rename-Item $_ -NewName ("new_name{0}.wmv" -f $i) -whatif}