# rename all files in a folder with incrementing numbers

Tags: powershell

i want to rename all files in a folder. i made a test folder with link files to the original files for the case if something wents wrong.
i searched hours on google and made a script with a few code snipplets.

this is my script:

```
$i = 1
cd "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\test"
get-childitem -filter "*" | %{rename-item $_ -newname ('filename_s01e{0:D3}.lnk' -f $i++)}
```

when i launch the script i get an error that renaming isn't possible because the item doesn't exist at *originalfilename*.lnk

i tried to change the filters and the filename but i have no clue why it's missing the items.

thx for help!

Comment: I think the problem is the way you're using the .lnk files.  Why not just use the -WhatIf switch?

Comment: Is this essentially what you are trying to do? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523043/how-to-loop-through-files-and-rename-using-powershell

Comment: if i use the whatif switch with the original files, i get the same error. i used the answer from this question as a template: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18304025/bulk-renaming-of-files-in-powershell-with-sequential-numeric-suffixes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `Rename-item $_` your sending setting the 1st positional parameter, `-Path`, equal to `$_` casted as a string(which will be the filename). The problem with `-Path` is that it doesn't support special characters very vell, which I'm guessing you have in your filename.

If you had used `$_ | Rename-Item`, the cmdlet would have linked up the `FullName` property with `-LiteralPath` parameter in the cmdlet. `-LiteralPath` is an alternative to `-Path` which works better with special characters, and because of that it's used as default for parameter-binding in pipelines.

By using the approach below, we will tell your script to use `-LiteralPath` and link it with the full path of the file, `FullName`, which should solve your problems. This is the recommended way to use the cmdlet if you're using a foreach-loop instead of  `Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item`.

Also, if you want all files in a folder, you don't need to use filter. Try the sample below.

```
$i = 1
cd "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\test"
get-childitem | %{ Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName ("filename_s01e{0:D3}.lnk" -f $i++) }
```

You could also include the folderpath in the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet and create your variable in the foreach-loop like:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\test" | 
% -Begin { $i = 1 } -Process { 
    Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName ("filename_s01e{0:D3}.lnk" -f $i++)
    }
```

Comment: thx you helped me alot. I had to upgrade to powershell v3 but now i got it perfectly working with this line: 
    get-childitem | sort-object name | %{ Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName ("filename_s01e{0:D3}.lnk" -f $i++) }